# Is there a manifold $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ s.t. $H^k(M)=\mathbb{R}$ for $k=1,2,3$? (deRham cohomology groups)

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

I was thinking the following: First, note that $\mathbb{S}^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and we have the deRham cohomology groups $H^{k}(\mathbb{S}^1)=\mathbb{R}$ for $0\leq k<2$ and $0$ otherwise, but $\mathbb{S^1}$ is not embedded on $\mathbb{R}$ ($\mathbb{S}^1$ is of dimension one). This motivates a curiosity: Is there a manifold $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $H^{k}(M)=\mathbb{R}$ for $k=1,2,3$? (In analogy to the case of $\mathbb{S}^1$ but now embedded in a space of the same dimension of its dimension) Of course such manifold must be of dimension 3, but I can't imagine the shape and topology it must be. Anyone know such example of manifold?

Comment: No, because any $3$-manifold which is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ can't be compact (or has boundary). This implies that the top homology is $0$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip But is it a general result? If the manifold is not compact then its top homology is always zero?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip and if we allow it to has boundary?

Comment: yes it is a general result that the top homology of a connected manifold is nonzero iff it is closed (compact and boundaryless) and orientable.

Comment: I think @CheerfulParsnip means cohomology, not homology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = S^1 ⨆S^2 ⨆ S^3 \subset \mathbb R^4$. Then, clearly $H^k(X)=\mathbb R$ for $k=1,2,3$.

It is not possible to achieve this as a subspace topology of $\mathbb R^3$. That is to say that a three dimensional object cannot have a four dimensional hole. Existence of such an object would give rise to an injection/embedding $S^3 \to \mathbb R^3$, which is impossible.

Note: ⨆ here is the disjoint union of topological spaces.

Comment: $S^1\vee S^2\vee S^3$ is not a manifold, but you can take a regular neighborhood to get a non-closed example.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip "Formally, a (topological) manifold is a second countable Hausdorff space that is locally homeomorphic to Euclidean space". Hm, $X$ definitely looks like a manifold to me. I mean $\lor$ to be the disjoint union, by the way, in case you were thinking I meant wedge union (like gluing the points together). I just mean a separate circle, sphere, and 3-sphere in four dimensional ambient space, if that wasn't clear..

Comment: $X$ is not a pure manifold, or an $n$-manifold for any $n$ -- it is simply a manifold $M$, and $M \subset \mathbb R^4$.

Comment: the problem is the wedge point.

Comment: Fixed the notation to match disjoint union. ⨆. Not wedge. Hope it is clear now. Apologies for the confusion with the symbol.

Comment: how do you define de Rham cohomology for that kind of manifold? I only know the definition for smooth orientable manifolds of a fixed dimension